# In Microsoft Excel, how does one have a default value of a cell that changes when data is entered but revert back to the default if data is deleted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sign in sheet that has multiple column titles and would like to have a default value in each column. The intent is when data is not entered there is a value there that states what information to enter, changes to the data that is entered, and if that data is deleted reverts back to the default data.

I have tried researching a solution to this and cannot come up with a clear solution. From conditional formatting to instructional cells, I am just not sure what the way forward is.

I have tried data validation, using ISBLANK, and conditional formatting  for equal to and text that contains.

Comment: You can do this with a conditional statement in the formula.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using conditional formatting is equal to, and text that contains. I tried data validation as well but that did not give the desired result. I have also tried a formula using the ISBLANK value. If I am doing wrong it is entirely possible. I am not a 100% with Excel.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show what you have tried exactly,

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches, using **Data Validation** or **VBA code**.

Using **Data Validation**, you can specify different rules for what a user can enter into a cell. On top of that, you can set a message for the user with the instructions he requires to fill the information correctly, and it'll appear when the user enters the cell.

Using **VBA code**, you need to add the following code snippet to your project:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1") = "" Then
        Range("A1") = "None"
    End If
End Sub
```

It'll do what you asked. If the user deletes the default text on the cell, it will print a message (in this case, "None"). You can customize the target cell or message as you require.